# Want to add background color to each item of Bottom Navigation Bar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-bottomnavigation

I have to create a Bottom Navigation Bar with a background for each item like below.[image]

Comment: can you include your current snippet and what is the issue you are getting

Answer (score 1):

Try using some code like this:

```
Material(
  color: Colors.white,
    child: Ink(
      decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(),
      ),
      child: IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.android),
        color: Colors.white,
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    ),
);
```

Which gives an output of this button:
[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idb80.png)

Here is the link to the documentation about this: [Link to documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/IconButton-class.html#material.IconButton.2)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you @gazahaza but I want to give the background to icon and label both.